# getting the error for installing packages using "python setup.py install"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried to install a few packages such as htmllib, dnspython, tzlocal and stopit but for all of them I can same error:

```
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/ :[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed. <ssl.c:749> -- some packages may not be found.
```

I have searched for the issue but the only solution was talking about adding to trust lists using pip which is not may case. Can anyone help me whats the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails with "connection error: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:598)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

Comment: Why do you think that "trust lists using pip" is not your case?

Comment: @ForceBru Because I am getting error using pip for every thing and was thinking to install packages directly

Comment: I always get this:  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement packagename no matching distribution found for packagename.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org pytest-xdist

pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting this: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytest-xdist  no matching distribution found for pytest-xdist.. and I am getting this one for every thing I tried using pip

Comment: Please show the command you are using  as well the error message.

Comment: I have used the one you mentioned here: pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org pytest-xdist

Comment: Your install, setuptools may need update:
On Linux or OS X:

pip install -U pip setuptools

On Windows:

python -m pip install -U pip setuptools